# Eclipse preferences: How to hide value associated with some key

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My project has some preferences which includes username and password for some service. Password is stored in preferences and it is encrypted. But problem is when I export All preferences and then import them in another workspace password is also transferred to second workspace. I don't want this behaviour. How do I hide password when user export all preferences.

Comment: Did you use the Eclipse Secure storage for that? http://blog.vogella.com/2011/09/22/eclipse-secure-storage-of-preferences/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the Eclipse Secure storage for that:

See e.g. [Lars Vogel's blog post: *Eclipse Secure storage of preferences*](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/09/22/eclipse-secure-storage-of-preferences/)